# MySQL Trigger Is Not Inserting Date/Time String Into Column

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

Here's my trigger. Updating a row in `event` does not set a date/time string in `sf_timestamp`. New to triggers so I am not sure how to debug.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `event_stamp` 
BEFORE UPDATE ON `event` 

FOR EACH ROW 
  BEGIN
      SET NEW.sf_timestamp = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d %T');
  END;;

DELIMITER $$
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Can you show an example of a value you are trying to use in an UPDATE statement? What do you expect the trigger to do? What is it doing instead? Is there an error, what is the error message? If the result of the UPDATE is a wrong value, what was the value, and what did you expect it to be? Please help us help you, answer these questions.

Comment: I am guessing the that I need to remove the reference to NEW.sf_timestamp from DATE_FORMAT(). That field was just added to the table and will be blank for all records. Removing it should insert the formatted date string for current date and time - I hope.

Comment: Shouldn't the `END` be followed by the delimiter character you just set? `END $$` and then you reset the delimiter to default value `END ;`

Comment: what i want the trigger to do is set the sf_timestamp to the current datetime string whenever that record is updated

Comment: @pensum please post a response with code if you think you have an answer.  Thank you.

Comment: Oh my bad. I didn't think it was the solution, which is why I only gave a comment. But if it helped you, I will post as an answer. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define a `DELIMITER`, you need to keep that same delimiter until you are done with the block you are trying to declare. In this case, you are trying to create a new trigger and you need MySQL to interpret the whole block with multiple lines as one and ending them with the default `;`

But when you are done, you have to `END` the block with the `DELIMITER` you have set earlier **as following**:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `event_stamp` 
BEFORE UPDATE ON `event` 

FOR EACH ROW 
  BEGIN
      SET NEW.sf_timestamp = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d %T');
  END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless your update statement includes a value for sf_timestamp, that field likely doesn't have a value to be formatted. If you are attempting to update the timestamp to represent the time when the record is updated, why not just use the current time?

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `event_stamp` BEFORE UPDATE ON `event` 
FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
        SET NEW.sf_timestamp = now();
    END;;

DELIMITER $$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `event_stamp`     
BEFORE UPDATE ON `event` 
FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
        SET NEW.sf_timestamp = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d %T');
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Followed @pensums suggestion and this worked for me